# start Activity from Asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, start-activity

I know this question has been answered several times before and i have read most of them but i do not understand why they are not working for me.

I am building sort of a Webcrawler, therefore i have an Asynctask that parses the HTML code to my desired Variables in one class.

I know want to start the Asynctask vie OnClick which is not the Problem, but i want to start a different Activity after the Asynctask has parsed the HTML Code.

Since it is an Asynctask i thought it would be best to start the Actitivty in the OnPostExecute of it.

My code is very simple and basic but i dont know why i have problems with it.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        if(dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        startActivity(new Intent(context, DetailView.class));
    }
```

the context is a variable in which i have the context of the MainActivity and that works perfectly fine for me at different points in the Asynctask to create a Toast.

DetailView.class is the Actitivity i want to start which works fine from the MainActivity but not at this place.

The problem is that the Compiler tells me he expects android.app.Activity and the actual Argument is "new Intent(context, DetailView.class)"

I am sorry for such a simple and already often answered Question but i dont know how to get it to work.

Thank you for any Answer.

Comment: is your AsyncTask an inner class? Is the outer class extending Activity?

Comment: I think, you are using `this` context. Have you tried to replace it with `getBaseContext()` or `MyActivity.this`?

Comment: does it crash ? whats the error ? also post your whole code and logcat

Answer (score 0):

Perfect Blackbelt, My outer class didnt extend Activity, that was the solution.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can't update UI on background thread. Showing toast and dialog is a way of update UI.

You can `publishProgress(...)` in method `doInBackground()` and update UI in `onProgressUpdate()`

Comment: Showing the Toast is not the Problem, wrapping it in the Handler works. The Toasts are shown the Dialog as well, but the DetailView Activity doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, DetailView.class));
```

This works now, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of answers but I use this for my apps:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, mainmenu.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
```